# How do I set up a new Solr core using data from an existing core?

Tags: database, solr, lucene, jetty

I saw that there was a similar question asked 3 years ago, but I figure it's OK to duplicate as 1) the existing q is 3 years old and 2) I have different problems and a different version of Solr.

Here's the story. I was given a copy of the "Index" directory of an existing Solr core by a collaborator. I am trying to set up my own core locally and using that index. The existing core was from a Solr 4.1.0 installation. (I have tried, and failed, to set up both Solr 4.3.1 and Solr 4.1.0.) I'm running Solr with Jetty.

What's the problem, you ask? Well, I replace the config files (schema.xml and solrconfig.xml) in the default example core with the ones my collaborator gave me. And then I run Jetty. This creates a new Index folder. I delete the contents of that Index folder and copy in the contents of the Index folder I was given.

The result is that Solr gives me an error indicating that "segments" files cannot be found. So I noticed that there are two files (segments.gen and segments_1) that are created with the initial Index folder. I experiment with leaving those in the Index folder but replacing everything else. Now Solr seems to be working (the browswer interface is working) but it reports "Num docs: 0" and a *:* query gives me 0 results.

Anyone have any ideas? I'm happy to provide more info. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `segments.gen` and `segments_1` from the original index. Ask you collaborator to give you those files also. But since you mentioned that collaborator gave you a copy of index folder, so you must already be having those files.

Note that it might not be necessary that `segment_1` is present in your original index copy. It can be segment_N. Whatever `segment_` file is there in original copy, copy that to new index and restart jetty.

`segments.gen` records the current generation (the _N in segments_N) in the index, as a fallback in case directory listing of the files fails to locate the segments_N file (eg on filesystems, like NFS, where the directory listing may come from a stale cache)

Comment: Ok, this makes a lot of sense, and is sort of what I assumed after reading up on the segments files. My collaborator insisted that he gave me the entire Index folder, so we're just going to have to get on the same page. Anyway, thanks for confirming my suspicions.

Comment: By the way, just to double-check: 1) Is there no way of generating a new segments_N file that will work? 2) Is there no way that my collaborator could be running a Solr core without a segments_N file? Thanks in advance!